# Асинхронная авторизация и вывод пользовательских фото одним кликом

Tags: oauth, асинхронность, instagram, auth

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос в названии: асинхронная авторизация и вывод пользовательских фото одним кликом - Инстаграмм.

Как это возможно?

Напишите, пожалуйста, какие ключевые слова, которые я мог упустить, которые еще можно поискать, или саму суть. Если приведете примеры - вообще идеально!

Проблема №1. У меня не получается авторизироваться через OAuth 2 получая code. Для этого нужна перезагрузка страницы. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно сделать по-другому? Пробовал играть с `window.open`, но не могу получить параметр `code` обратно. Также пробовал отловить это событие, чтобы потом аяксом сделать запрос на получение токена и после получить изображения пользователя.

Проблема №2. Если использую респонсив = токен, вопервых, все равно перезагружается страница, во вторых, сколько ни искал, не понял как этот токен изъять и сделать так, чтобы в строке браузера он не показывался. И опят главная проблема - перезагрузка.

Comment: > Знаете как можно по-другому???

Знаю.
1. Прочитать [документацию](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)
2. Переслать пользователя, использовуя `response_type=token` вместо `response_type=code`.
3. Получить `access_token` в хэше.
4. Записать в `localStorage`.
5. Извлечь из `localStorage` на оригинальной странице по событию.

Comment: @Andrey090909, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Comment: Fike, СПА - СИ - БО !!!!! )))))) Все получилось!! УРА!!!
После долгих дней и ночей уже опустились руки. А теперь все получилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=*****&redirect_uri=http://ваш_сайт.ru/файл.php&response_type=token');">Войти через инстаграм</a>
```

Код файла "файл.php":

```
<script>
var regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m; 
    m = regex.exec(location.hash.substring(1));
    localStorage.setItem('token', decodeURIComponent(m[2])); 
    window.opener.CALLBACK_FUNC();
    window.close();
</script>
```

окно само закрывается.
Токен становится доступен по адресу **localStorage.getItem('token')** и обратится к нему можно обратится с любого места JS.
Функция, которая выполняется в родительском окне - это **CALLBACK_FUNC()**

Вот и все. вуаля. Счастье!